# LeetCode: Longest String Chain (Java)

Tags: java, programming-challenge, graph, dynamic-programming

1. For the question, I had a pretty messy solution so I would like some advice on how to better use Java to make the code a bit cleaner.
2. Also, a semi-hack that I did that I'm not proud of is checking if `words.length == 0` at the beginning and returning `0` if so, so that I can initialize `int longestSeen = 1` (if there exists a word, the smallest chain must be at least 1).

   In reality, if we haven't processed the graph to find the longest chain, we should have `int longestSeen = 0`. My solution only adds to the adjacency list `adjList` if there exists a relation (e.g. 'ab' -> 'abc'), so for the case where there are no chains and every word is a lone island, I'm not checking for the longest chain length at all and am basically just straight up returning `1`. This makes sense and would be more time efficient than initializing the `adjList` with all the words, but it feels hack-y to me.
3. I had `int[] longestChain` outside of the longestStrChain method and I'm not sure how to get around this.

**Problem:**
https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-string-chain/

Given a list of words, each word consists of English lowercase letters.

Let's say `word1` is a predecessor of `word2` if and only if we can add exactly one letter anywhere in `word1` to make it equal to `word2.`  For example, `"abc"` is a predecessor of `"abac".`

A word chain is a sequence of words `[word_1, word_2, ..., word_k]` with `k >= 1`, where `word_1` is a predecessor of `word_2`, `word_2` is a predecessor of `word_3`, and so on.

Return the longest possible length of a word chain with words chosen from the given list of `words`.

**Example:**

```
Input: ["a","b","ba","bca","bda","bdca"]
Output: 4
Explanation: one of the longest word chain is "a","ba","bda","bdca".
```

**Solution:**

```
class Solution {
    int[] longestChain; // memoization for longest chain length for fromKey vertex
    
    public int longestStrChain(String[] words) {
        if (words.length == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        Map<String, Integer> wordToIndex = new HashMap<>(words.length);
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> adjList = new HashMap<>(words.length);
        longestChain = new int[words.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            wordToIndex.put(words[i], i);
        }
        for (String word : wordToIndex.keySet()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                String curr = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i+1, word.length()); // take one char out at a time for each word and see if it's part of words[]
                if (wordToIndex.keySet().contains(curr)) {
                    int fromKey = wordToIndex.get(curr);
                    int toKey = wordToIndex.get(word);
                    if (adjList.keySet().contains(fromKey)) {
                        List<Integer> vertices = adjList.get(fromKey);
                        vertices.add(toKey);
                        adjList.replace(fromKey, vertices);
                    } else {
                        adjList.put(fromKey, new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(toKey)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        int longestSeen = 1; // longest string chain so far
        for (Integer fromVertexIdx : adjList.keySet()) {
            longestSeen = Math.max(longestSeen, getChainLength(fromVertexIdx, adjList));
        }
        return longestSeen;
    }
    
    private int getChainLength(int fromVertexIdx, Map<Integer, List<Integer>> adjList) {
        if (longestChain[fromVertexIdx] > 0) {
            return longestChain[fromVertexIdx];
        }
        longestChain[fromVertexIdx] = 1; // min string length is 1 (vertex contains no edges)
        if (adjList.keySet().contains(fromVertexIdx)) {
            for (Integer edge : adjList.get(fromVertexIdx)) {
                longestChain[fromVertexIdx] = Math.max(longestChain[fromVertexIdx], getChainLength(edge, adjList)+1);
            }
        }
        return longestChain[fromVertexIdx];
    }
}
```

Comment: Code doesn't compile for `Arrays.asList(toKey)`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a speedup, I was expecting some sorting to be performed on size; I'm a bit surprised to only see maps in this regard. HashMaps behave well, but I wonder how much faster it would be if the size was taken care of *before* trying to find stuff by comparison (of hashes or values).

One problem I have with your solution in general is the naming of the variables. Yes, an `index` is an `index` and a `vertice` is a `vertice`. But an index *of what?*. It doesn't help if you then throw everything on one heap; one method with a single helper method. The method goes 4 deep and contains other branches as well.

```
class Solution {
```

Ah, yes, that's of course not a good distinguishing class name.

```
int[] longestChain; // memoization for longest chain length for fromKey vertex
```

That doesn't seem right to me, just forward it using a parameter, but don't use fields unless necessary (e.g. this makes the function not-thread safe, while accomplishing nothing). Furthermore, in Java you don't declare anything until you're prepared to initialize it.

```
if (words.length == 0) {
    return 0;
}
```

Using a special case for zero is nothing to be ashamed of. Zero is such a special number that the Romans didn't even have a representation of it. However, it does make sense to check if your algorithm doesn't run even if you have a zero (does it?).

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> adjList = new HashMap<>(words.length);
```

To a new developer it is entirely unclear what `adjList` means here.

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    wordToIndex.put(words[i], i);
}
```

This should be performed in a separate method, so that you get the least amount of loops (and don't use `i` to mean separate things).

```
 String curr = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i+1, word.length()); // take one char out at a time for each word and see if it's part of words[]
```

What about `smallerWord` or similar as name instead of `curr`?

Comment: Thank you that you had also an eye on my answer! +1

Answer (score 3):

### Data Design

your major flaw is your poor data design. As described in the question you have

1. **find out when one word is a predecessor of another**
2. **A word chain is a sequence of words, where one word is a predecessor of another**

### 1. find out when one word is a predecessor of another

this describes an algorithm on how to find out if one word is a predecessor of another. you should provide **at least one method** that does only this and only this:

```
private final String word;

public boolean isPredecessor(String predecessor) {
    if (predecessor == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (predecessor.length() != word.length() + 1) {
        return false;
    }
    if(predecessor.length() == 1){
        return true;
    }
    boolean breakReached = false;
    int breakIndex = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < word.length(); index++) {
        if (word.charAt(index) != predecessor.charAt(index)) {
            breakReached = true;
            breakIndex = index;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int index = breakIndex; index < word.length(); index++) {
        if (breakReached && word.charAt(index) != predecessor.charAt(index+1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

compare letter by letter and if you come to **one breaking difference** you continue with index+1 - if all other match, then we have a predecessor. You iterate only once over the whole word.

[image]

### 2. A word chain is a sequence of words, where one word is a predecessor of another

that leads to the following data structure where you can store a word and its predecessors. Such a data structure makes the code very clearly to read later.

```
public class Predecessor {

    private final String word;
    private final List<Predecessor> predecessors = new ArrayList<>();

    public Predecessor(String word){
        this.word = word;
    }

    public void addPredecessor(Predecessor predecessor){
        predecessors.add(predecessor);
    }


    public List<Predecessor> getPathToRoot(){
        List<Predecessor> path = new ArrayList<>();
        if(!predecessors.isEmpty()){
            path.add(this);
            path.addAll(predecessors.get(0).getPathToRoot());
        }
        return path;
    }

    public boolean isPredecessor(String predecessor) {...}

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        if (!predecessors.isEmpty()){
            return "['"+word + "'->'"+predecessors.get(0).word+"']";
        }
        return "['"+word + "']";
    }

}
```

### applied output

the algorithm with these applied methods and data structure would be fairly clear:

```
public int longestStrChain(String[] words) {

    //create predecessor list 
    List<Predecessor> predecessors = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String word: words){
        Predecessor newOne = new Predecessor(word);
        predecessors.add(newOne);
        for(Predecessor predecessor: predecessors){
            if(predecessor.isPredecessor(word)){
                predecessor.addPredecessor(newOne);
                predecessors.add(newOne);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //find out the longest one
    List<Predecessor> candidate = null;
    int depth = 0;
    for(Predecessor predecessor: predecessors){
        List<Predecessor> path = predecessor.getPathToRoot();
        if (path.size() > depth){
            depth = path.size();
            candidate = path;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(candidate);
    return candidate.size();
}
```

### notes

since the data structure provide information *from a --> to b* it's result is -1 to the original size

> [a --> ba] , [ba --> bca] , [bca --> bdca]

### notes

since we don't care which predecessor we choose (`predecessors.get(0)`) it's a bit unpredictable which word chain we get. - but we're guaranteed to find one longest!

Comment: k think it's called *primitive obsession* when you prefer primitive datatype `Map<String, Integer>` over a proper data type.

Comment: That should be `isSuccessor()` the way you wrote it. The predecessor is the *smaller of the words*, and you compare to `#word + 1`.

Comment: Or make that `Predecessor.isPredecessorOf(String successor)` I guess.

Comment: This design is a ton better, but it really requires its own code review, to be honest.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes you are absolutely right. Here is even more code review to do than on the original question. I should have sticked with a more minimal answer, where I only point out the flaw of the design...

Comment: Something that really got me, even though it is very minimal, is `breakReached = true;` -> after the loop, if no break is reached, then the last character only differs, right? So success & stop! (but I upvoted for the design, because the errors don't invalidate it).

Comment: Very nice @Maarten Bodewes... Honestly I was quite a bit eager when I wrote my answer. The missing data type just pained me, so I shot and asked afterwards... Stupid me...